# Designing UVC LEDs strip using WS2811 LED driver IC

Tags: led, led-driver, led-strip

I'm designing a UVC LEDs strip using WS2811 LED driver ICs. I'm using the Vishay UVC emitting diodes [3] having the forward voltage of 6.8 V and the radiant power typically 2.5 mW at 20 mA. I used one LED per WS2811 chip as the typical output constant current of the WS2811 IC is 18.5 mA. If I use more than one LED per IC then a constant current of 18.5 mA will be divided which I don't want. I used a 5 V regulator to regulate 6.8 V to 5 V to power the WS2811 chip.

- In the WS2811 datasheet, there are two sample circuits, (i) using 5 V
  and (ii) 12 V power supply. I'm a little bit confused about how they fed 12 V to the VDD pin of the IC as the maximum voltage of the VDD pin is 6-7 V.
- Also, they say that R1 is used as the IC internal LDO divider resistance and the value is 2.7K. how they calculate this resistance
  value.
- And what would be the R1 value for 6.8 V?
- if I use a 5 V to power the IC and 6.8 V to power the UVC LED and use one LED per IC
  would work? Any recommendations would be very helpful. Thank you.

[image: Circuit designs provided in the datasheet]

[image: UVC LEDs strip]
UVC LEDs strip

[3] https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3098116.pdf

[4] https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf

Comment: For me, at least, this question is confusing because you are using an addressable RGB LED PWM driver to drive UVC LEDs for which I can see needing constant current, but that's about it.

Comment: @jyelton UVC LED brightness can be controlled by PWM. Question why somebody need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ws2811 can control 3 LEDs, your design is excessive. 3 channels, each is 18.5 mA maximum, PWM to control brightness. Totally chip with LEDs may consume around 50mA. Power on Vdd 6-7V, chip has internal LDO. In case of 12V voltage is divided, some internal and external resistance. 6.8V could be connected to Vdd, 100 Ohm resistor for filter, separate power source unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Could you please also explain how did you calculate the total current of the circuit? In my opinion, If each LED will draw current of about 18.5 mA then the total current drawn by the LEDs would be around 90 mA, not 50 mA. Is this right?

Comment: @user16449631 3 channels, each 18.5 mA. 18.5x3=55.5. How did you get 90?

Comment: I meant the total current consumption of the circuit, the total number of the LEDs in the circuit are 5, so 5*18.5 = 92.5 mA.

Comment: I got another circuit design in which I used 6 LEDs and two ICs (3 LEDs per IC) but when made a prototype of the circuit and tested it, the whole circuit draw about 40 mA current. Do you know why?

Comment: @user16449631 the guiscient current of chip appr 1mA. So the max current will be according to your calculation. WS2811 gives the possibility to control current, you can make less.

Comment: @user16449631 Current is depend how you control Ws2811, what number you sent to programm chips.

Comment: I used the Adafruit_NeoPixel.h library and the numbers that I sent are (255, 255, 255) using the following function:  pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(255, 255, 255)) in Arduino IDE. So I thought by specifying the maximum brightness, the LEDs should draw current of about 6*18.5 = 111 mA.

Comment: @user16449631 All sources shows around 60 mA. My experience with WS2812 is the same. Your calculation is right. May be some mistake in programm or ampermeter. Dig dipper, check the signal with oscilloscope.

Comment: @user16449631 Another guess the 6.8V is not enough, switches inside WS2811 has some drop voltage. And current trough LED lower than 18.5mA because the LED's drop voltage smaller than nominal. Try increase voltage to LEDs anodes. 9V may be.